# How to remove unwanted space between rows and columns in table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

How do I remove the extra space between the rows and columns in the table.

I've tried changing the margin, padding, and various border properties on the table and tr and td.

I want the pictures to all be right next to each other to look like one big image.

How should I fix this?

**CSS**

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Tera Byte Video Game Creation Camp</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></link>
</head>

<body>
  <table class="mytable" align="center">
    <tr class="header">
      <td colspan="3"><img src="images/home_01.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="top">
      <td colspan="3"><img src="images/home_02.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="link-row">
      <td><img src="images/home_03.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_04.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_05.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="link-row">
      <td><img src="images/home_07.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_06.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_08.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="link-row">
      <td><img src="images/home_09.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_10.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_11.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="link-row">
      <td><img src="images/home_12.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_13.png" /></td>
      <td><img src="images/home_14.png" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="bottom">
      <td colspan="3"><img src="images/home_15.png" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Add this CSS reset to your CSS code: ([From here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css))

```
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

It'll reset the CSS effectively, getting rid of the padding and margins.

Comment: There is a comment if you read saying:

/* tables still need 'cellspacing="0"' in the markup */

Comment: what happens if you are using a lot of css in you page and you don't want to reset it?

Comment: It's probably best practice to use a reset or some sort of framework and build from there. However in this case you will have to reset each style ie. table { padding: 0px; border: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; etc }.... Checkout http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html for more.

Comment: You can skip a lot of them since it's only for the tables.

Comment: This is excessive, doesn't answer the question, and isn't even a full reset.  Perhaps isolate the code that's relevant, explain it, and then suggest using a reset.

Comment: `border-spacing` works only if `border-collapse: separate`. So, adding it is not required: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-spacing.asp

Comment: why `border-spacing: 0` ? it has no effect when `border-collapse: collapse`

Comment: This answer is a god-send. There is so much white space in html that is given to you whether or not you want it or ask for it, and it becomes confusing to deal with. Shouldn't the default be that there is no white space and that you add it as you need it rather than assuming everyone will want what is given to them?

Answer (score 278):

Adding to vectran's answer: You also have to set `cellspacing` attribute on the table element for cross-browser compatibility.

```
<table cellspacing="0">
```

EDIT (for the sake of completeness I'm expanding this 5 years later:):

**Internet Explorer 6** and **Internet Explorer 7** required you to set [cellspacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement.cellSpacing) directly as a table attribute, otherwise the spacing wouldn't vanish.

**Internet Explorer 8** and later versions and all other versions of popular browsers - **Chrome, Firefox, Opera 4+** - support the CSS property [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing).

So in order to make a cross-browser table cell spacing reset (supporting IE6 as a dinosaur browser), you can follow the below code sample:

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black; /* Style just to show the table cell boundaries */
}


table.no-spacing {
  border-spacing:0; /* Removes the cell spacing via CSS */
  border-collapse: collapse;  /* Optional - if you don't want to have double border where cells touch */
}
```

```html
<p>Default table:</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Removed spacing:</p>

<table class="no-spacing" cellspacing="0"> <!-- cellspacing 0 to support IE6 and IE7 -->
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 76):

This worked for me:

```
#table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
```

Comment: Just `border-collapse` was enough for my case.

Answer (score 58):

For images in td, use this for images:

```
display: block;
```

That removes unwanted space for me

Answer (score 13):

Just adding on top of Jacob's answer, for `img` in `td`,

```
body {line-height: 0;}
img {display: block; vertical-align: bottom;}
```

This works for most email clients, including Gmail. But not Outlook.
For outlook, you need to do two steps more:

```
table {border-collapse: collapse;}
```

and set every `td` elements to have the same `height` and `width` as its contained images. For example,

```
<td width="600" height="80" style="line-height: 80px;">
    <img height="80" src="http://www.website.com/images/Nature_01.jpg" width="600" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
table 
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

will collapse all borders separating the table columns...

or try

```
<table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0;">
```

do all **cell-spacing** to 0 and border spacing 0 to achieve same.

have a fun!

Comment: `<table cellspacing="0" border-spacing: 0;>` is invalid markup!
`<table cellspacing="0" style="border-spacing: 0;">` would be correct

Answer (score 8):

For standards compliant HTML5 add all this css to remove all space between images in tables:

```
table { 
    border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td {
    padding:0px;
}
td img {
    display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

All I had to do was add:

```
line-height: 0px;
```

in my

```
<tr ...>
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 6):

Try this,

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse; /* 'cellspacing' equivalent */
}

table td, 
table th{
padding: 0; /* 'cellpadding' equivalent */
}
```

Answer (score 5):

setting Cellpadding and cellspacing to 0 will remove the unnecessary space between rows and columns...

Answer (score 3):

```css
table{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table td {
  border: 1px solid black; /* Style just to show the table cell boundaries */
}


table.no-spacing {
  border-spacing:0; /* Removes the cell spacing via CSS */
  border-collapse: collapse;  /* Optional - if you don't want to have double border where cells touch */
}
```

```html
<p>Default table:</p>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>Removed spacing:</p>

<table class="no-spacing" cellspacing="0"> <!-- cellspacing 0 to support IE6 and IE7 -->
  <tr>
    <td>First cell</td>
    <td>Second cell</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There are other answers that provide the OP's question, and they were posted some time ago. When posting an answer, please make sure you add either a new solution, or a substantially better explanation, especially when answering older questions.

Answer (score 2):

adding this line to the beginning of the file s worked for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

modifying the css to set the proper border properties did not work until i added the above line

Comment: This is the ONLY thing that worked for me!  +1 and THANK YOU!  I had it set to Strict instead of transitional.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and none of the suggestions from several posts worked, I tried them all. My problem turned out that the table I was creating is nested in another table, inheriting on its properties. I needed to override the container table.

In this example, SuColTable  is class on the table.

```
.SuColTable tr {
    border: none !important;
}

.SuColTable td {
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border: none !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}


.SuColTable {
    border-collapse: collapse !important;
    border: none !important;
    border-spacing: 0 !important;
    border-collapse: separate !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
// all padding would be padding: 0 !important
```

The border-collapse, border:none and border-spacing get rid of table/row/column line. The padding 0 calls get rid the padding from the container table. I had to including !important on every style for it work, in order override the container table styles.

I have padding_top, left and bottom (instead of only padding) because I have two other classes that control the padding_right.

```
line-height: 0px;
```

Line-height zero makes the row one line high. If you have several lines, they are compressed into one line.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the TRs that have a colspan and see if it changes anything?

I have experienced colspans and rowspans to be pretty nasty when it comes down to accurate table-designs. If your images look alright without the colspan-TRs, I'd start from there and build a nested tableset.

Also your style.css doesn't seem to be complete, maybe there's something wrong there? I'd at least add `padding: 0; margin: 0;` to the table (or to the class "mytable").
Make sure, your images don't have spaces and/or borders, too (e.g. by adding `img { border: 0; }` to your stylesheet).

Comment: removing the TR's with a colspan does nothing. adding the padding and margin does nothing either