# How to remove Html table Cell spaces in Html5?

Tags: html, cellspacing

I have html script as below

```
            <header>
            <div id="header">
                <table class="headertable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="headertable">
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <div id="site-title" class="site-title">
                                            <img src="~/Images/site-title.gif" alt="site-title", title="site-title" id="img-site-title" style="display:block" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                                 <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="fullbannerad" class="fullbannerad">
                                            <img src="~/Images/fullbanner.gif" alt="fullbannerad", title="fullbannerad" id="img-fullbannerad" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div id="halfbannerad" class="halfbannerad">
                                            <img src="~/Images/halfbanner.gif" alt="halfbannerad", title="halfbannerad" id="img-halfbannerad" />
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                 </tr>
                              </table>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                           <div class="site-logo">
                              <img src="~/Images/site-logo.gif" alt="site-logo", title="site-logo" id="img-site-logo" />
                           </div>
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                   </table>
            </div>
        </header>
```

below is the css

```
table.headertable {
border-spacing: 0;
border-collapse:collapse;}

.headertable td {
padding:0;}
```

There is a space added between td & table(nested table) elements to the page in the code below (this I checked in chrome debugger)

```
<td>
   <table class="headertable">
```

How can I resolve this issue? Please suggest.

Comment: toss this into a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 0):

Extra whitepsace in your document should be ignored by the browser. If you having problems with your page layout, it won't be due to extra spaces in that position.

Comment: Hi Steve, thanks for your reply, the actual issue I am experiencing with is in different context. I wish I could add a screenshot. My issue is more close to [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table)

Comment: This [blog](http://webdesign.about.com/cs/tables/qt/tiptablespaces.htm) helped me understand where my issue could be at.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by making use of nested divs with float property. HTML5 does not encourage nested tables for layout design. Ref to [this link](http://webdesign.about.com/od/layout/a/aa111102a.htm) for more details. Thanks Jennifer, you made my day.

Below is my code changes

```
            <div id="header" class="clearfix">
                <div id="sitetitle" style="float:left">
                    <a href="/Publication/Config/title">
                        <img src="/images/site-title.gif" alt="site-title" , title="site-title" id="img-site-title" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                 <div id="logo" style="float:right">
                     <a href="/Publication/Config/logo">
                        <img src="/images/site-logo.gif" alt="site-logo" , title="site-logo" id="img-site-logo" />
                     </a>
                 </div>
                  <div id="bannerad" style="float:left">
                      <a href="/Publication/Config/fullbanner">
                        <img src="/images/fullbanner.gif" alt="fullbannerad" , title="fullbannerad" id="img-fullbannerad" />
                       </a>
                      </div>
                    <div id="halfbannerad" style="float:right">
                        <a href="/Publication/Config/halfbanner">
                            <img src="/images/halfbanner.gif" alt="halfbannerad" , title="halfbannerad" id="img-halfbannerad" />
                        </a>
                    </div>

            </div>
```