# Create a grid with no spaces using table html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm trying to build a grid in html but I want to remove spaces between my cells, and I can't find.

```
<table id="gameGrid" cellspacing="0" >
    <tr class="gridRow" >
        <td class="box" ></td>
        <td class="box" ></td>
        <td class="box" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow" >
        <td class="box" ></td>
        <td class="box" ></td>
        <td class="box" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="gridRow" >
        <td class="box" ></td>
        <td class="box" ></td>
        <td class="box" ></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and the CSS:

```
#gameGrid{
border:1px solid black;
border-collapse: collapse;
padding:0;
margin:0;
border-spacing: 0;
} 
#gameGrid .gridRow{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#gameGrid .gridRow .box{
margin:0;
padding:0;
background-color:green;
height:16px;
width:16px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

an example: http://jsfiddle.net/sLG2D/1/

I saw this post but nothing works
[How to remove unwanted space between rows and columns in table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `display:inline-block;` rule from `#gameGrid .gridRow .box`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sLG2D/4/)**

Answer (score 2):

you are displaying your td's as inline-block. remove that.