# img tag is leaving gap in table cell in internet explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer, browser, html-table, padding

Here is the HTML

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr><td><img src="/someimage"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><img src="/someimage"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

I want to stack two images without any gap. Thus cellspacing and cellpadding set to 0.

In all browser, it works fine. But in IE, I see small gap between two images.

I can't figure why it is doing this. Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Do you have any CSS rules applied to the table?

Comment: Did you try removing the space between the `<td>` and the `<img>` tags? Sounds silly, but that's IE for you. :)

Comment: Same happens in firefox, btw..

Comment: @Dai no css applied to the table.

Comment: @SeeMeCode yes there is no space between <td> and <img>
Yes, it happens in Firefox 17 as well.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Images,_Tables,_and_Mysterious_Gaps  add display:block to image... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table

Comment: @nevermind yes making <img> as block element removed the gap. Thank You.