# Wrong css ">" selectors (by me)

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am trying to design a chess board with css3, but it seems like my selectors are wrong. [Here is my JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/loloof64/nxvse1hd/6/)

So why can't I see the designed test blue and red borders around lines and cells ?

**html**

```
<body>
    My chess board
    <table class="chess_board">
       <tr class="chess_line">
          <td class="chess_cell black_cell white_piece"><span>&#9812;</span></td>
          <td class="chess_cell white_cell white_piece"><span>&#9813;</span></td>
          <td class="chess_cell black_cell white_piece"><span>&#9814;</span></td>
          <td class="chess_cell white_cell white_piece"><span>&#9815;</span> </td>
       </tr>
       <tr class="chess_line">
          <td class="chess_cell white_cell"><span>&#9820;</span></td>
          <td class="chess_cell black_cell"><span>&#9821;</span></td>
          <td class="chess_cell white_cell"><span>&#9822;</span></td>
          <td class="chess_cell black_cell"><span>&#9823;</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    My another chess board ... to be drawn !
</body>
```

**css**

```
table.chess_board > tr.chess_line {
  background-color: blue;
}

table.chess_board > tr.chess_line > td.chess_cell {
  border: 2px solid red;
 /*
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  width: 1.0em;
  height: 1.0em;
  text-align: center;
  */
}

table.chess_board > tr.chess_line > td.chess_cell > span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0.1em;
}

table.chess_board > tr.chess_line > td.white_cell {
  background-color: rgb(217, 245, 2);
}

table.chess_board > tr.chess_line > td.black_cell {
  background-color: rgb(89, 34, 21);
}

table.chess_board > tr.chess_line > td.white_piece {
  color: rgb(179, 48, 63);
}
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: side note: `>` means `direct descendant of what precedes the >`

Comment: Yes, that what I really meant, just did not know about the tbody tag

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because browser automatically puts `<tbody`> element between `table` and `tr` while creating the DOM from HTML.

Check DOM structure in Firebug (or similar tool)

You can either remove `>` operator like:

```
table.chess_board tr.chess_line {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxvse1hd/8/

or add `tbody >` like:

```
table.chess_board > tbody > tr.chess_line {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxvse1hd/9/

Comment: How ! I am too much restrictive and accurate ! Ok gonna remove this ">" selector, seems better than adding tbody according to me (what it will be in later html ?)

Comment: Yes, I think that it's better way too, unless you have nested tabled.

Comment: I've a new version : http://jsfiddle.net/loloof64/nxvse1hd/11/ But this time, and maybe last question, I would like to remove the gaps between cells : I've tried margin:0, margin:-0.2em inside chess_cell, but does not seems to work. A workaround for this ? Regards

Comment: Ok. found solution here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `>` of your css, the Browser adds `<tbody>` and `<thead>` elements in your source code.

```
table.chess_board > tr.chess_line {
  background-color: blue;
}

table.chess_board tr.chess_line td.chess_cell {
  border: 2px solid red;
 /*
  font-family: serif;
  font-size: 2.3em;
  width: 1.0em;
  height: 1.0em;
  text-align: center;
  */
}

table.chess_board tr.chess_line td.chess_cell > span {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0.1em;
}

table.chess_board tr.chess_line td.white_cell {
  background-color: rgb(217, 245, 2);
}

table.chess_board tr.chess_line td.black_cell {
  background-color: rgb(89, 34, 21);
}

table.chess_board tr.chess_line td.white_piece {
  color: rgb(179, 48, 63);
}
```

Comment: Browsers *never* create implicit thead elements - they only do so with tbody.

Answer (score 1):

dragoste is right, your css should be like:

```
table.chess_board  tr.chess_line {
  background-color: blue;
 }

table.chess_board  tr.chess_line  td.chess_cell {
  border: 2px solid red;
```

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers add a `<tbody>` in DOM. and when a `<tbody>` is there, the selector ">" will not work anymore:

just use in your case the simple inheritance selector.

updated solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/nxvse1hd/7/

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
table.chess_board  tr.chess_line {
  background-color: blue;
 }
```

instead of:

```
table.chess_board > tr.chess_line {
  background-color: blue;
}
```