# Image split into table: Remove space between rows

Tags: html, css, image, html-table

Maybe the solution is simple but I've not found anything that answers my question yet...

I want to split an image into several, so I can clic it or hover it, and create cool interactions on what appears to be a single image. Problem, my image has an undesired space between the rows of the table.

So here is exactly what I mean to do :

```html
<div id="blocfour">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step2.png" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step3.png" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step1.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step4.png" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

I tried "collapse" in CSS, and other numerous things, but naaah, the damn space is still here - or maybe I did it the wrong way. Any idea how I can get rid of it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove unwanted space between rows and columns in table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by changing `img`'s layout to `block`:

```css
td img{display:block}
```

```html
<div id="blocfour">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step2.png" /></td>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step3.png" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step1.png"/></td>
        <td><img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step4.png" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried it on my website but it looks like my problem is not that simple eventually. The wordpress theme includes already so many CSS, it does not help... :S

Here is the link where I'm trying (and struggling) to set this up :
http://cuisines-et-bains.com/script-test/

Any idea what i should do ?

Comment: @GaletteRaclette: you can use it with `!important` to rewrite wordpress stylings.

Comment: Ow yes ! That worked :)
So i just added this line to my CSS :
td img{
 display:block !important;
}

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you use text in the table you can reset `font-size` for table cells in CSS.

```css
table {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="blocfour">
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step2.png" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step3.png" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step1.png" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="http://cuisines-et-bains.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/step4.png" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```