# how to remove spaces from this th and td elements

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am creating CRUD application and don't know how to remove this left and right spaces coming in th and td

thanx in advance :)

Comment: Provide some code

Comment: Most likely need to remove the [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

Comment: You need to put your code instead of the screenshot for us to understand what is going on under the hood. This way it is impossible to answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove unwanted space between rows and columns in table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279396/how-to-remove-unwanted-space-between-rows-and-columns-in-table)

Comment: `border-spacing: 0;` and `border-collapse: collapse;` maybe help. We need to see how your code is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this to your table in css:

```
#yourTable{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help. If you accept and like my answer it would be great because someone disliked my answer and I lost 2 reputation

Comment: i would definatly do that but i need 15 reputation to like someones answer ......would do it after i get the reputations :)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it's a **border-spacing** CSS property set to 1 or so pixels on your **table** element.

You need to inspect the **table** and child **td** and **th** elements in Chrome or whichever browser's developer tools, and see what CSS styles are attached to those elements.

Specifically, you're checking the table element for **[border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)** (as Pete mentions above) with **[border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse)** set to '*collapse*', and then also double-check **[padding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)** on the td/th elements, because it seems like you've some padding on those cells as well, from the screenshot.

```
table { 
   border-collapse: separate; /* for border-spacing to work */
   border-spacing: 0px; /* or however much space you want */
}

td, th { 
   /* or however much padding you want */
   padding-left: 0; 
   padding-right: 0;
}
```

If there's already styles attached to these elements, you'll need to find where they're defined in the CRUD application framework you're developing in to change them...or alternatively, create more specific CSS rules to target this table in your application, so the default values aren't affected for other parts of your application, if that's desired.